# Production site kept in public repository. How secure it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

For Testing i cloned a github repo from private to public. It had details about the api keys and credentials in the readme.Got notified about this by a stranger. Then i removed the public  repository.Now what all should i change so that there can be no attacks made on the production site? Like change of api keys,changing passwords,etc

Comment: Well, all the information that you didn't want to be public, like passwords, API keys, credentials should be changed ASAP. Since it all was in a public repo, you should consider it all to be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is not longer secure if private security details have been made public. You'll need to change all your secrets including API keys and passwords, including database connection details.

Also, be sure to make your cloned repo private or remove it completely. Just adding a commit that deletes the private details **will not** help. If you want keep the repo public, you'll need to follow [GitHub's guide for removing sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

Answer (score 0):

Github has sample .gitignore files for almost any kind of project known. Check out the repo: https://github.com/github/gitignore